# Using longtable, scalebox and tabular

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a very long table (with 200 rows) and it doesn´t fit just on one page. I had tried to use "longtable" but I got an error message and I can´t create the pdf file. Could you please let me know how to use longtable with tabular and scalebox?

Many thanks in advance!

This is what I've tried:

```
\begin{longtable}[H]\caption{\large{Title}}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{1.3}{
\begin{tabular}{lcc}\hline\hline
\textbf{County}  & \textbf{N of obs} & \textbf{\%}     \\ 
\hline
Lake1    &  Observations  &  Percentage    \\
Lake2    &  Observations  &  Percentage    \\
..
..
Lake200  &  Observations  &  Percentage    \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Don't use `scalebox` to make a table fit onto a page. This will lead to inconsistent font sized throughout your document.

Comment: `longtable` is a tabular-like environment, so youl shouldn't nest a `tabular` inside. Actually, your table preamble should be `\begin{longtable}{lcc}`, and you should never use a ` center` environment inside a table, as it adds spurious vertical  spacing. Furthermore, a longtable is centred by default.

Comment: `longtable` definitely is a better approach than `scalebox`. However, you used it incorrectly. `\begin{longtable}{lcc}\caption{caption text}\label{key}\\ \hline County & N of Obs....`should work.

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[H]\caption{\large{Title}}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{1.3}{` you can not have `[H]` or `\begin{center}` or `\scalebox` around a longtable, if there is a tutorial suggesting this sort of markup please let us know so we can get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a xcorrect code. I replaced the `\hline`s with the rules of `booktabs`, which have some vertical padding and make tables look less tight, and the `caption` package to have control on the caption layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

 \null\vspace{0.72\textheight}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.33}
\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\captionsetup{font={large}, labelfont=bf, skip=4pt}
\caption{Title} \\
\toprule\midrule
\textbf{County} & \textbf{N\textsuperscript{o} of obs} & \textbf{\%} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
 \caption{Title (continued)}\\
\midrule
\textbf{County} & \textbf{N\textsuperscript{o} of obs} & \textbf{\%} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\itshape To be continued}
\endfoot
\midrule\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Lake1 & Observations & Percentage \\
Lake2 & Observations & Percentage \\
Lake Pipple-popple & Observations & Percentage \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
Lake197 & Observations & Percentage \\
Lake198 & Observations & Percentage \\
Lake199& Observations & Percentage \\
Lake200 & Observations & Percentage \\
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much . It worked perfectly !